# Importing a patch from one git repo into another

Tags: git

I have two repositories that share some code, but not all. Occasionally I need to cherry-pick a commit from one repository (the upstream) into the other (the downstream). Exploring in `git log` or `gitk` provides the commit hash, but I need an easy way to say "grab commit 1234abcd from repository ../UpstreamRepo and apply it here".

In this particular situation, I also want to be able to restrict the new commit to just one file (of known name) from the original. Ancillary files such as NEWS don't apply here and will just cause unnecessary merge conflicts. This is preferred but not required (other people may well have similar situations that don't need this).

Comment: Note that the import doesn't have to worry about merge conflicts. If they happen, I'll deal with them (probably with `git am --abort` and ignoring that commit). It just has to grab one single commit from a foreign repository and apply it here.

Comment: If it’s an upstream and downstream repository, why don’t you just add one repository as a remote to the other one and cherry-pick the change?

Comment: Because it's not that close a connection. There's basically one file that's shared between them, and it isn't even all of that file. Actually, in my specific use-case, the file doesn't even have the same name, so I have a third sed command in the filter - changing from globals.pike to window.pike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I have currently is this:

`git -C ../UpstreamRepo show 1234abcd|sed '1d; 2s/^Author/From/'|git am -`

The sed in the pipeline is for two reasons: firstly, `git show` puts the commit hash on the first line, which `git am` objects to; and secondly, `Author:` on the second line isn't recognized by `git am` as an authorship marker. So it's a bit ugly.

All the usual `git show` subcommands are available, including restricting it to a specific file, and using branch-relative commit naming rather than grabbing a specific hash.

Answer (score 5):

If the repos A and B are on the same machine, or on two machines that can communicate with each other. The goal is to get one of B's commits and apply it to one of A's branches.

```
cd <path_A>
git checkout <branch_A>
git fetch <path_B> <ref_that_contains_commitB>
git cherry-pick <commitB>
```

If A and B are on two machines that cannot communicate directly. This approach could also work for A and B on the same machine.

```
cd <path_B>
git format-patch <commitB> -1
#a xxx.patch is generated
#move this patch to A's workground.
cd <path_A>
git checkout <branch_A>
git am <path_xxx.patch>
```

Another approach that you may want to know.

```
cd <path_B>
git bundle create B.bundle <ref_that_contains_commitB>
#B.bundle is generated
#move this bundle to A's workground.
cd <path_A>
git checkout <branch_A>
git fetch <path_B.bundle>
git cherry-pick <commitB>
```

If A and B cannot communicate directly, but they both can access repo C, maybe in github or some public server.

```
cd <path_B>
git push <url_C> <ref_that_contains_commitB>:<ref_in_C>
cd <path_A>
git fetch <url_C> <ref_in_C>
git checkout <branch_A>
git cherry-pick <commitB>
```

The `git cherry-pick` part could be `git rebase` or `git merge` instead in some specific cases.

Update:
If commitB changes some files but you want only file_b's changes,

```
cd <path_B>
git diff <commitB>^ <commitB> -- <file_b>    >   b.patch
#move b.patch to A's workground
cd <path_A>
git checkout <branch_A>
git apply <path_b.patch>
git add .
git commit -m 'xxx'
```

OR

```
cd <path_B>
git format-patch <commitB> -1 -- <file_b>
#xxx.patch is generated
#move xxx.patch to A's workground
cd <path_A>
git checkout <branch_A>
git am <path_b.patch>
```

Comment: In all cases, I want the flexibility to be able to cut the commit down to just one file. (Will edit the question to clarify this.) Also, I don't really want to fetch the entire target repo, as the first one does. `git format-patch` is close (and is what I used before I crafted the new method), but very clunky. The bundle is interesting - will look into it - but looks clunky too.